# Before I found out vs. Before finding out

Tags: verb-forms

Non-native speaker here.
Could someone explain the difference between these two?

> I had messaged them ten times before **I found out** they cut ties with our company.
> I had messaged them ten times before **finding out** they cut ties with our company.

Are both of them correct?
What is the grammatical term for the second one?

Comment: Both grammatical, especially if you insert a second 'had' before 'cut'. // [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/before) mentions the 'before + ing-clause' construction (prepositional phrase).

Comment: Both sentences are grammatically correct.
I usually use -ing form with ‘before’ or ‘after’, though.